# Text align to image not working css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to vertical align my icons with my text in wordpress so far I have the following

```
<div class="media oppsite">
  <div class="media-left pull-right"> <?php query_posts('p=89'); ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?><div style="padding-top:42px;"></div></div>
  <div class="media-body text-right">

    <h2 class="media-headingb" style="text-align:center;"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>



    <?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class'  => 'imgtop' ) ); // show featured image
    } 


?><?php the_content(); ?>

            <?php endwhile;?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Which is not working imgTop is a class that verticle aligns text to top of image but I dont understand why its not aligning properly here is the site.

http://innovativeapps.dk/

Comment: try making the `h2.media-headingb` `display: inline-block`, then your `vertical-align` should work, assuming you want it to be `text-top`. Or use `middle` if you want the text to be vertically centered by the `.imgtop`

Comment: why should the h2 make a diff though its sep ?

Comment: if I understand what you're trying to do, the image isn't aligning by the h2 because the h2 is block, so the image will always be below the h2. To get the text beside the image, the easiest way is probably just to change it to `inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you forgot to include your image inside `media-left` class.

```
<div class="media oppsite">
      <div class="media-left pull-right"> <img width="286" height="286" src="http://innovativeapps.dk/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Icon-1.png" class="imgtop wp-post-image" alt="Icon-1" srcset="http://innovativeapps.dk/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Icon-1.png 286w, http://innovativeapps.dk/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Icon-1-150x150.png 150w" sizes="(max-width: 286px) 85vw, 286px"><div style="padding-top:42px;"></div></div>
      <div class="media-body text-right">

        <h2 class="media-headingb" style="text-align:center;">Value First</h2>



        <p>Vi udvikler og udgiver din app helt gratis, tilmed giver vi dig en hel måned til at benytte alle dens funktioner kvit og frit. I denne måned vil du selv opleve en stigning i omsætningen som følge af din nye app.<br>
Skulle appen efter den første måned ikke leve op til dine forventninger, eller er der en anden grund til du ikke ønsker at fortsætte, så sletter vi bare appen igen og du bliver ikke trukket en krone.</p>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I had it their previous but still it was not alinging properly

Comment: I can see the above changes in your site now and it is looking fine. What you exactly want?

Comment: its fine now mate thanks for that il mark you as answer.

Comment: Happy to help..:)

Comment: now the fella saying he wanting it centers ffs some people

Comment: You are using `media classes` incorrectly, you dont need to add `pull-left` or  `pull-right ` to them.  Just add `vertical-align:middle` to media items. They are by default set to `display:table-cell`. Go through this link https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_media_objects.asp if you are confused how to use them. As you original problem was resolved you can mark the above answer as accepted as this will help other users also.